# html5 IE9 Cache issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-appcache

I have the following:

```
    var webappCache = window.applicationCache;

    switch (webappCache.status) {
         case 0:
            console.log("Cache status: Uncached");
            break;
       case 1:
             console.log("Cache status: Idle");
             break;
        case 2:
            console.log("Cache status: Checking");
             break;
         case 3:
             console.log("Cache status: Downloading");
            break;
         case 4:
             console.log("Cache status: Updateready");
            break;
       case 5:
             console.log("Cache status: Obsolete");
             break;
         default:
             console.log("Cache status: unknown");
    }
```

In IE 9, it can't understand what webappCache.status is. I also read that IE 9 does not support applicationcache. Is this true?

Comment: IE 9 says `typeof window.applicationCache` is `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is only supported in IE10 +

[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=appcache)